# How to add font-awesome within <asp:Button>

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I had a html/css code like this
using font at http://fontawesome.io/icons/
and `<i class="fa fa-times"></i>` is the font icon.

```
 <button  class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> restore</button>
```

Now, I want to change it to ASP.NET WebControls . However I can't add font within it. Anyone has way,thanks.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="restore"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with the default asp.net button you will need to use a HTML button and give it runat=server attribute:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnRun" class="btn btn-mini" title="Search">
    <i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> Search
</button>
```

So use code behind with this you add:

onserverclick="functionName" 
To the button, then in your C# do:

```
protected void functionName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello World!!!");
}
```

So final button looks like:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnRun" onserverclick="functionName" class="btn btn-mini" title="Search">
    <i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> Search
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this way, but I want to learn how to use the default